# Basic Algebraic Number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading Algebraic Number theory by Jurgen Neukirch. While proving Theorem 6.6 of chapter 2, he makes the following statement:
Let $(K,| \ |)$ be a complete non-archimedean valued field with a discrete valuation . Let $O$ be the discrete valuation ring with the unique prime ideal $p$ and $\kappa=O/p$.  If $f(X)=a_0+\cdots a_n X^n$ is a a primitive, irreducible
polynomial such that $a_0a_n\neq 0$ polynomial over $K[X]$, then in $\kappa(X)$
\begin{equation}
\overline{f(X)} = \overline{a}\ \overline{\phi(X)}^m
\end{equation}
for some irreducible polynomial $\overline{\phi(X)}\in \kappa(X)$ and a constant $a$.

I am unable to understand why there is only one polynomial appearing in the factorization of $f(X)$ mod $p$.

By a primitive polynomial, I mean that $\overline{f(X)}\neq 0$ and $|f|=max\{|a_o|, \cdots, |a_n|\} = 1$

Comment: You didn’t say whether the $K$ was to be complete. If it is, then you argue as follows: If there were two such irreducible polynomials over the residue field, then you could lift that factorization back up to the original field, by (strong) Hensel.

Comment: No, there wasn't any mention of completeness. But I guess I can use your hint because if we take the completion of $K$, say $\hat{K}$, then we can use Hensel lemma there and the argument will follow since $\hat{O}/\hat{p}\cong O/p$.

Comment: I think you really do need completeness. Consider $K=\Bbb Q$, with $2$-adic valuation, not complete. And the polynomial $F(X)=\Phi_7(X)$, the cyclotomic polynomial, degree $6$. Irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, of course. But over the residue field $\Bbb F_2$, it factors into two different, and thus relatively prime, cubics, both primitive. Need I say that over the completion $\Bbb Q_2$, $F$ is no longer irreducible?

Comment: Thanks, @Lubin. I have edited the question.